# change a variable while a function is running in react

Tags: reactjs

i have this problem.

```
function Request() {

   var con = true

   function stop_con(){
        con = false
   }

   async function handleSubmit() {
        await sleep(10000)

        if(con = true){
            console.log("should run")
        }
        else {
            console.log("should not run")
        }
        return;
   }
}
export default Request
```

I start with runing the handleSubmit() function. while the funtion is on sleep i run the stop_con() function but it dose nor reflect. Is ther any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
function Request() {

   var con = true

   function stop_con(){
        con = false
   }

   async function handleSubmit() {
        stop_con()
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("Delayed for 10 seconds.");
        }, 10000)

        if(con = true){
            console.log("should run")
        }
        else {
            console.log("should not run")
        }
        return;
   }
}
export default Request
```

Comment: Sorry i did not make it clear. the stop_con() funtion will be runnig from outside by button while the handelsubmit function in sleeping. so this wil not work